Vanishing Cech cohomology implies vanishing sheaf cohomology
Let $(\mathsf C,\tau)$ be a site. Denote by $\iota:\sf S\to P$ the inclusion functor from the category of abelian sheaves into the category of abelian presheaves on $(\mathsf C,\tau)$.
Fix a sheaf $F$ in $\sf S$, with $\check{H^p}(U,\iota(F))$ vanishing for all $p\gt 0$ and all objects $U$ in $\sf C$. I'm trying to see why $H^p(U,F)$ vanishes as well for all $p\gt 0$ and all objects $U$ in $\sf C$.
Attempt at proof.
Let now $U$ be a fixed object in $\mathsf C$. We have a first quadrant spectral sequence defined by $E^2_{pq}=\check{H^p}(U,R^q\iota(F))$.
Now, the column $E^2_{0q}$ vanishes for $q\gt 0$ in general, and the assumption that $\check{H^p}(U,\iota(F))=0$ implies that also the row $E^2_{p0}$ vanishes for $p\gt 0$.
These facts, using purely arguments of homological algebra on the spectral sequence, imply that $H^1(U,F)$ and $H^2(U,F)$ vanish.
However I'm stuck at $p=2$, so I'd like a suggestion about the tools to use at this point. Should I insist in reasoning about first quadrant spectral sequences which vanish on the axis (but not in the origin) or should I use that $\check{H^p}(U,\iota(F))=0$ for all $U$? For example expressing $E^2_{pq}$ as $\check {H^n}(U',F)$ for some $n\gt 0$ and $U'$ in $\sf C$? Or again, I thought to express $E^2_{1q}$ and $E^2_{2q}$ as  $H^n(U',F)$ with $n=1,2$ and $U'$ in $\sf C$, in order to make the first three column vanish (except the origin), and maybe start a proof by induction.
I'm doing it as an exercise so I'd prefer just to receive an hint about the approach, I'm not really looking for a solution. Thank you in advance

The inclusion functor should be $\iota :\sf S \to P$, not $\iota : \sf P \to S$. Can you evaluate the presheaf $R^q\iota(F)$?

The statement is a special case of the Verdier hypercovering theorem.  See, for example, Proposition 6.6 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03925v3, or the references to Jardine, Rezk, Artin–Mazur and Verdier therein.
The Verdier hypercovering theorem expresses the sheaf cohomology at $U$ as a homotopy colimit over all hypercovers of $U$.  In our case, the target $F[p]$ is $p$-truncated, so when we map a hypercover into it, the hypercover also gets $p$-trunacted.  For a fixed $p$, Čech covers of $U$ are homotopy initial among all $p$-truncated hypercovers of $U$, so the homotopy colimit can be taken over all Čech covers of $U$, which yields Čech cohomology.

There was in fact an assumption on $(\mathsf C,\tau)$, that for any covering ${U_i\to U}i$, all finite fibered products of the form $U{i_0}\times U\cdots \times_UU{i_r}$ exist. Does it mean that the site is hypercomplete? But anyway I don't think that hypercovering theorem or hypercompleteness have ever been touched in my course; for example the paper you linked is absolutely extraneous to me

@EzioGreggio: The assumption on the existence of fiber products is harmless and can always be enforced by including the corresponding fiber products of representable sheaves in the site.   Since in the case under consideration the target happens to be $p$-truncated, the hypercompleteness assumption can be removed.  I edited the answer accordingly.  Hypercovers first arose in the context of algebraic geometry, e.g., in the work of Verdier and Artin–Mazur.  They play a fundamental role in the construction of the sheafification functor, as witnessed by the Vedier hypercovering theorem.
